# d3.hsl fails on Safari

Tags: d3.js, safari, color-space, hsl

I put together a simple HTML page:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
 
  //ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
  ctx.fillStyle = d3.hsl(120, 0.5, 0.5);
  
  ctx.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myCanvas"> </canvas>
```

On Chrome it correctly gives a green background.
On Safari (8.0.6 -- current at time of writing) however it gives a black background.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue has to do with String coercion. Basically, the proper way to get `d3.hsl` to return a color string (`"#40bf40"` in your case) is to call `.toString()` on the HSL object (see [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Colors#hsl_toString)). So in your case, it would be

```
ctx.fillStyle = d3.hsl(120, 0.5, 0.5).toString()
```

which will fix the Safari issue.

The reason it worked in Chrome without the `.toString()` is because Chrome's JS engine chose to convert it to a String for you - much like JS converts a number to a string in something like this: `5 + "2" // "52"`. Internally it's actually calling `(5).toString() + "2"`. Safari happened to not decide to `.toString()` it, which is why it didn't work.